# In Spotfire I want to display an image from the database

Tags: image, spotfire

I have images stored in the database that I want to show in Spotfire.  I've found how to display an image from a webpage but not one directly from the SQL database.  Spotfire defaults to string type for the image.  I tried editting it at the Info Link stage and forcing it to be a blob, but when I render it as an image I just see [..].

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately Spotfire doesn't support BLOB or binary data.

what you *can* do is store your images on a server somewhere, then in place of the binary data in your database, store the URL to the image. you can then display it in a table as suggested in the [Spotfire manual](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html//table/table_images_in_tables.htm).